# Css align to center td with two floating elements

Tags: html, css

I have table that i need all the content to be align center, and in one td i have image with span after the image.
I need all the images in the tr td to be aligned vertically so i apply float left to them but i loosed the align center. What the solution for this?

```
 <body>
   <table class="table table-striped">
     <tr>
       <td>
       <img src="http://placehold.it/50x20" alt="">
       <span>short text</span>   
       </td>
       <td>some text</td>
       <td>some text</td>
       <td>some text</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
       <img src="http://placehold.it/50x20" alt="">
       <span>longer text text</span>   
       </td>
       <td>some text</td>
       <td>some text</td>
       <td>some text</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  </body>

.table tr td {
  text-align: center;
}
.table tr td:first-child span, .table tr td:first-child img  {
 float:left;
}

.table tr td:first-child img   {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/D4VbnesF3FnwnNHI25nB?p=preview

I need the images to be Aligned with all the other images, also the span.

Comment: No problem, when I remove `float: left;`, images are vertically centered. You can add `vertical-align: middle;` if you want.

Comment: No i need then to show the same vertical line

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want

CSS

```
.table{ width: 100%;
        position:relative;
}

.table tr td {
  text-align: center;
    position:relative;
}
.table tr td:first-child img  {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.table tr td:first-child:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0px;
    top:50%;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/50x20) no-repeat 0;  
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    content:"";
}



 <img src="http://placehold.it/50x20" alt="">

.table tr td:first-child span {
text-align: center;
}

.table tr td:first-child img   {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/twg7873e/5/)**

Comment: No, i need them to be like they are but on the center.

Comment: Ok..i update the demo and css. Is this what you want?

Comment: I need the images to be Aligned with all the other images, also the span.

Comment: Hmmm. you need to have another cell for the image

Comment: Only with css, but you need to put the image in the css. Can you check is this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be centered both horizontal and vertically you must remove the **float** an put a vertical-align:middle

Like this:

```
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
    <img src="" style="display:inline-block;" />
</td>
```

Of course you can also do this using classes...

Comment: The images not in the same vertical line.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding, what do you mean by "not in the same vertical line"?

Comment: I need the images to be Aligned with all the other images, also the span

Comment: With the span at the bottom of the image?

Comment: No, the span aside the image like how it his now.

Comment: Then I believe you need a different TD for the IMG.

Comment: And then is not gonna be near the span

Comment: If you want the images to be all aligned you can't add the span to the equation, otherwise all the horizontal sizes would change, so the best you can do is to add a TD just for the IMG, and Float the SPAN on the adjacent TD.

Comment: If you can make this as answer with fiddle.